# Putting the same shortcuts in every LyX page

Tags: math-mode, macros, shortcut

I have math macro shortcuts that look like that:

[image]

Every time I open a new document, I want them to be at the top of the page. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options for this type of workflow:

1. Create a document where you keep all of your macros, say "shared-macros.lyx". Then, in every new document you can go to Insert > File > Child Document and select "shared-macros.lyx".
2. You can create a template that has your macros (and anything else, such as document settings) so that when you start a new document you can just go to File > New from Template. If you want to go this approach, note that in LyX 2.4.0 (not yet released) you will be able to just go to File > Save as Template. If not in 2.4.0, see below.
3. You can create a template by first going in your file browser to your user directory (in LyX, see Help > About LyX to locate your LyX user directory), and then putting a .lyx file in the subdirectory "templates". For me, on Ubuntu, this directory is here: `/home/scott/.lyx/templates`.
4. If you *really* want to make it so when you start a new file you have those macros ready, do the same as (3) but save the .lyx file in the templates directory as "defaults.lyx" and overwrite the existing defaults.lyx after backing it up. Make sure you backup the file before you overwrite it. Now when you go to File > New in LyX it will start you off with what you want.
5. One final option is to use a clipboard manager. I use CopyQ (https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ). You can save pieces of text/lyx/anything that you frequently want to paste.